# How to request optional parameters?

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline

This is regarding Timeline Actions.

When I submitted my Action for approval, I did not ask for optional parameters. If I want to start doing so, how can I request optional parameters for the approved Action?

Or do I have to create a new action ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add optional parameters, you will have to delete the old action and submit a new one with the parameters enabled. Facebook doesn't let you edit the action after it's been approved, except for the basic settings.